# Writing CLI: recursive function unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js

I was writing a command line interface to my node program when I encountered some unexpected behavior.

```
// Starts command line prompt bot
// @param {Function} callback - callback upon finshing CL inputs
function main(callback) {
    this.args = []; // store CL args
    this.consoleOutputs = ["Enter input1: ", "Enter input2: ", "enter input3: "];
    this.nextInput = function(consoleOutputs, numInputsLeft) {
        if (numInputsLeft == 0) { callback.apply(null, args); } // done, stop recursing and run callback
        // write output to prompt user
        process.stdout.write(consoleOutputs[consoleOutputs.length-numInputsLeft]);
        process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
            var text = process.stdin.read();
            if (text !== null) {
                console.log(numInputsLeft);
                args.push(text);
                // recurse to print next output and wait for next input
                nextInput(consoleOutputs, numInputsLeft-1);
            }
        });
    }

    nextInput(this.consoleOutputs, consoleOutputs.length);
}
```

I expected numInputsLeft to decrement: 14, 13, 12, etc.
Instead, numInputs Left was stuck at 14, 14, 14, etc.

Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is the line

```
nextInput(consoleOutputs, numInputsLeft-1);
```

Here every time it will be only 3-1 = 2, because we are not storing the results anywhere. So everytime it tooks the same value.

I tried with this code and its working fine for me.

Please try this hope it helps.

```
function main(callback) {
this.args = []; // store CL args
this.consoleOutputs = ["Enter input1: ", "Enter input2: ", "enter input3: "];
this.numInputsLeft = consoleOutputs.length;

this.nextInput = function(consoleOutputs, numInputsLeft) {

    if (numInputsLeft == 0) {
      console.log("Ends here !!");
      process.stdin.removeAllListeners('readable')
      return callback(null, args);
    }

    console.log(consoleOutputs[consoleOutputs.length-numInputsLeft]);

    process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
        var text = process.stdin.read();
        if (text !== null) {
            args.push(text.toString().trim());
            numInputsLeft--;
            nextInput(consoleOutputs, numInputsLeft);
        }
    });
}

nextInput(this.consoleOutputs, this.numInputsLeft);
}

    main(function (arg1, arg2) {
      // console.log(arg1);
      console.log(arg2);
    });
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. However, I am still confused. I expected numInputsLeft := numInputsLeft-1 on the recursive call. For example:

function series(n) {
 if (n == 1) { return 1; }
 return n * series(n-1);
}

n := n-1 on each recursive call. series(4) returns 24.

Is it because nextInput is not a real recursive function, because the "recursion" happens in an asynchronous callback?